# Making a "go away" material in HeroForge

Tags: miniatures, hero-forge

So, I was tinkering around with a model in HeroForge, and came to a situation where I want to make a connecting rivet (a piece of material that connects a worn item to a character, or the light grey thing inside the red circle in the picture below) as inconspicuous as possible in the rendered 3D model. (It's not meant for printing or painting.)  How can I best go about doing that?

[image: picture of "rivet" in HeroForge, with a red circle added]

Comment: you don't get the STL, right?

Comment: @Trish Hero Forge gives you the STL file for your mini when you purchase it. See https://www.heroforge.com/digitaldownload/

Comment: @ThomasMarkov it does, but making it *go away* requires the STL, and the STL does not contain the color render.

Comment: @Trish yeah, I'm just working at the renderer level here, not exporting a STL of this

Answer (score 1):

### Removal doesn't work without buying & downloading the model

HeroForge is designed to make objects printable and thus includes connector pieces that ensure that the items intersect and will stay together.

They can only be removed if you download the file (which doesn't include surface colorations and patterns), and then you would need to alter the object file itself, removing the surfaces and possibly fixing holes generated by removing the connector piece.

### Hiding the crime...

If you don't buy and download the model, the best solution you have is tilting and turning the model in such a way that the connector piece is behind an other item, such as the shoulder or the item it connects to the body.